# Antimatter molecules properties

Tags: atoms

Do the antimatter molecules have the same chemical properties with matter molecules?Should we define electropositivity for antimatter molecules since the chemical bonding would be between positrons?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihydrogen as a start. I have not seen papers on anti-matter molecules (rather than single anti-hydrogen atoms), but may have missed something.

Comment: Yes I know anti hydrogen and I know anti helium as well.Now they are trying to make anti lithium which will be very cool

Comment: Well, cool or not, no molecules yet. Given the initial results on anti-hydrogen, one would generally assume that the bonding energies for molecules would be the same.

Comment: Molecules of antihelium exist and molecules of antihydrogen also exist.

Comment: Cool - do you have a link?

Comment: Dont make fun of me ok?Well if they managed to create low energy antihydrogen atoms then they would have made antihydrogen molecules as well .

Comment: I'm genuinely curious, since I haven't seen any papers claiming that. And, no, given how few antihydrogens have been made there is no particular reason to believe that they have made molecules. And, while antihelium has been produced, it doesn't make molecules normally.

Comment: Many many antihydrogen atoms havebeen  made . And lately there were created antihelium atoms/molecules by colliding gold atoms.

Comment: Oops, I retract my comment on antihelium - looks like a handful were observed at RHIC in 2011...

Comment: Look, there is a difference between a molecule and an atom - lets keep the terminology straight, particularly on Chemistry SE!

Comment: **There is no _other_  "anti"-stuff.** I mean, sure, there are certain particles which have come to be known by the moniker of "antiparticles", but this is solely a feature of our area of universe (or maybe of _all_ universe, because of the breaking of symmetry, but that's another question). The interaction of an antiproton and a positron is exactly the same as that of a proton and an electron. By _"exactly"_, I mean _"quite exactly, totally, to the very last digit, with all doubts bulldozed over"_. The antimatter is the same as the matter, only the other way around. No new theory is required.

Comment: Thank you Ivan but the properties of anti matter are not 100 per cent known.We dont know only one thing if antimatter has negative mass or regular mass but antimatter having negative mass is considered very unlikely.

Comment: A helium atom is not a molecule: https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/M/M04002.html A "monoatomic molecule" is an oxymoron.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - to be fair, there has been a lot of effort put into experimental validation of the symmetry between hydrogen and antihydrogen. Now, that was partly because there are some dark matter implications of an asymmetry. But, none of this really is particularly chemistry related.

Comment: Orthocresol so noble gases do not form molecules:)

Comment: Look:https://www.google.com/url?q=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9oLW5j-PiAhVOyqQKHWM-D7oQFjAAegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw2JdjgZ4gdyWRXZGvZXK0sx

Comment: Molecules are smallest non dividable amounts of given substance :-) But if a substance consists of smallest non dividable amounts of chemical element, formally atoms of noble gases as elements are at the same time molecules of noble gases as substances.But as they are identical, we are used and somewhat turned it to convention, not to speak about them as molecules.

Comment: With modesty, if antimatter molecules would exist, I think that we can reasonably assume the situation as described in your question. Either you reverse the order, or you call it positropositivity ;)

Comment: Haha yes positronegativity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an approximation based on the most accepted theories about cosmology (that I know of).

We currently consider that our observable universe is composed only of normal matter, by opposition with antimatter. Also, matter and antimatter should have the exact same physical and chemical properties.

However, there is a catch! According to the current theories, the Big Bang should have produced exactly the same amount of matter and antimatter, and both should have annihilated together by now. The fact that our universe is composed only(?) of matter implies that there is something fundamentally different between normal matter and antimatter which left an excess of normal matter.

Because we think that there must be a fundamental difference between the 2, we try to isolate antimatter and mesure some of its physicochemical properties to be compared with normal matter so we can determine where the current theory is wrong.

Comment: In principle they could be "identical" and a  very small excess of matter would have resulted in just matter left existing. But perhaps there are not enough photons around to allows for this possibility? Forgot the point, if the above is an idea of mine or if it something that my books considered and discarded.